# Autocomplete data stored in mySQL using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a web application in which the user is able to register people names in mysql database through a web server written in nodejs. I want to add a functionality of searching these names and I would like the application to autocomplete whatever the user is typing, based on the names stored in mysql database. Just like the search suggestions in Google.

How to do that for mysql using nodejs?

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way I have implemented it for a past project was by sending asynchronous queries to the database for each letter that was typed and then updating the page with returned results (as you get them) with JS. The queries themselves would be something along the lines of a string comparison (looking for a given subset of characters in an entry).

If you need more help I would recommend trying to get something basic working (i.e. make it so the webpage queries the database with a few characters and displays the names you are looking for) and expanding from there. If you run into a problem, feel free to post it here (with code) and we would be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you so much. It turned out to be easy. I almost get it done taking your advice :)